# Difference Between Copy and Move Operators in C++20 and Deleting Them

Tags: c++, copy, c++20, visual-studio-2022, move

So, I am just starting a video tutorial on creating a graphics engine in C++ using GLFW and Vulkan. I have already completed the LunarG tutorial, but the series I am watching goes into far more detail including how to effectively move functions into classes which I struggled with as I am only intermediate in C++, and I do not know every single operator or all the ins-and-outs of C++ yet.

The tutorial first recommends for a class to delete the copy constructor and assignment operator like:

```
EngineDevice(const EngineDevice&) = delete;
void operator=(const EngineDevice&) = delete;
```

I understand how this works since copying can cause a dangling pointer, but I am confused on exactly what the move operator does as the person then suggests doing:

```
EngineDevice(const EngineDevice&&) = delete;
EngineDevice& operator=(const EngineDevice&&) = delete;
```

What exactly can happen if the move operator is allowed or removed? Does this prevent moving the memory location of an object to a new pointer? I am not exactly sure what is happening here, but I am still fairly new to C++ operators and things like moving, copying, etc.

This might be a stupid question, but I am trying to learn, and having it explained to me is far easier than combing through C++ documentation as I can get quite confused. I appreciate any help given. I have searched StackOverflow already, but I could not find anything which explains exactly what I am wanting. I am sorry if I missed an older post.

I'm not sure what to add to this "What I've Tried" section, but I have tried learning the difference myself via the C++ documentation, but I got confused very quick. I understand what the copy constructor does, but I am very confused on the move operator.

If I understand the documentation correctly, moving is when you intend to delete the original object right after copying?

Comment: If the copy operations are manually deleted (or just manually defined in any other way), then the move operations get deleted implicitly. Manually deleting them doesn't change anything, and I wouldn't bother doing it.

Comment: Watching video tutorials is not a good way to learn c++. Instead use a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). If you `=delete` the copy operations then the move operations will be automatically deleted by the compiler. So you don't need to `=delete` them explicitly.

Comment: Usually you're choosing between allowing only moves (when the class contains something that can't be copied, like probably most of Vulkan resources), both copies and moves (where moving is a faster way of copying that messes up the original object), or neither copies nor moves (when the address must remain fixed; or when you just don't want to bother, like in your case).

Comment: *" moving is when you intend to delete the original object right after copying?..."* No, moving is nothing special. It doesn't actually move anything. This is why I recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which explains these basic things instead of video tutorials. Also before writing advanced code, basics should be cleared first.

Comment: "I understand how this works since copying can cause a dangling pointer." I don't have the definition for your class, but a implicitly defined move constructor does exactly the same thing for a (raw) pointer member (or any non-class member for that matter): it copies the member. No magic here. So if you don't want a implicitly defined copy constructor due to incorrect behavior with non-class members, you definitely don't want a implicitly-defined move constructor either. Also as others commented the move constructor is deleted anyway when you have a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: It is helpful to know that `=delete` is a form  of user-defined, and then refer to the [table](https://www.foonathan.net/2019/02/special-member-functions/) by [@HowardHinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant). On the other hand, if you don't want to copy an object because there are pointers to them elsewhere, moving also does not (and cannot) magically redirect those pointers to point to the new object because ultimately copy constructor and move constructor and any other constructor are just constructing new objects in a new memory location. Again, no magic here.

Comment: "Moving" often confuses, as an object can never be moved anywhere. The purpose of moving is to transfer (ownership of) resources of some kind. Think "I'm moving my things out of a house and into a new one", not "I'm moving this house to somewhere else".

Comment: @user12002570 Actually, I am a visual learner. Books are hard for me to digest. I how found videos to be much more helpful. I watch videos that cover the same topics as the books. I have already followed Vulkan documentation. Tutorials just help me to learn the ins-and-outs much faster than reading the documentation. I find it much easier to work on my own after following a tutorial. Books are not always the best.

Also, I know the basics of C++ already. You did not read my post. I'm learning the basics of Vulkan, and I have never removed operators in C++ before, so I was confused.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I understand it now! The user complaining that I am using video tutorials must not have read my post completely. I just have never removed operators before in C++ as I've never used advanced code before Vulkan. I ALSO completed the LunarG written tutorial and hand wrote everything and made sure I understood it. This video tutorial just uses advanced methods I have not used before in C++. I'm NOT using the tutorials as a shortcut. I follow them and look up every term and method and learn them before I write them. Hence why I am asking here to LEARN.